# How to make audio autoplay in ipad version 6.0.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there anyway to do this or is it possible as its disbaled by default,any thoughts would be helpful.

Comment: Hi, a bit of research will tell you everything you need. Have you Googled `How to make audio autoplay in ipad version 6.0.1`?

Comment: googling results are that apple has disabled this scenario of autoplay of media...so i could get forward and have no ideas of how to acheive this...

Comment: If Apple has disabled it, and no one has come up with a workaround, there is probably no way to do it.

Comment: @Pekka웃 oh ok, i'll del it.

Comment: i wish there is anybody who has worked on it an found solution...

Comment: Well, it's a restriction imposed by the browser vendor. It's there deliberately and by design. Any way around it is likely to get closed in the next update of the product.

Comment: thanks pekka for ur help...